# С# Получение/изменение уровня целостности файла

Tags: c#, pinvoke

Дамы и господа, доброго времени суток!
Мне сильно необходимо научиться менять **уровень целостности (integrity level)** для различных **файлов**. Увы, но мои поиски в Google не увенчались успехом. Был найден только код, который делает это на C++, и перевести его в C# не получилось - *pinvoke.net* не знает оформления ряда функции, которые используются в C++.

Есть у Вас какие-либо идеи, с чего хотя бы начать?
Если кого заинтересует, прикреплю код.

Comment: А почему бы просто не запустить `icacls.exe`?

Comment: @VladD можно и через icacls.exe, но в данном случае необходимо это сделать программно.

Comment: Ну, если очень надо, можно ж и icacls.exe запустить программно. Это если не найдётся прямого пути.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем, вышла следующая штука. В Интернете куча примеров, как изменить уровень целостности файла на C++. Следовательно, было решено написать DLL с функционалом языка С++ для использования в С#.

Вот три файла, необходимые для сборки.

**IntegrityLevel.h**

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Aclapi.h>
#include <WinError.h>
#include <Sddl.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <winnt.h>

using namespace std;

namespace IntegrityLevel
{
    extern "C" { __declspec(dllexport) int GetFileIntegrityLevel(LPCWSTR FileName); }
    extern "C" { __declspec(dllexport) bool SetFileIntegrityLevel(int level, LPCWSTR FileName); }
}
```

**IntegrityLevel.cpp**

```
#include "IntegrityLevel.h"

namespace IntegrityLevel
{
    int GetFileIntegrityLevel(LPCWSTR FileName)
    {
        DWORD integrityLevel = SECURITY_MANDATORY_UNTRUSTED_RID;
        PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = NULL;
        PACL acl = 0;
        if (ERROR_SUCCESS == ::GetNamedSecurityInfo(FileName, SE_FILE_OBJECT, LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, 0, 0, 0, &acl, &pSD))
        {
            if (0 != acl && 0 < acl->AceCount)
            {
                SYSTEM_MANDATORY_LABEL_ACE* ace = 0;
                if (::GetAce(acl, 0, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&ace)))
                {
                    SID* sid = reinterpret_cast<SID*>(&ace->SidStart);
                    integrityLevel = sid->SubAuthority[0];
                }
            }

            PWSTR stringSD;
            ULONG stringSDLen = 0;

            ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptor(pSD, SDDL_REVISION_1, LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, &stringSD, &stringSDLen); 

            if (pSD)
            {
                LocalFree(pSD);
            }
        }

        if (integrityLevel == 0x0000)
            return 0;
        else if (integrityLevel == 0x1000)
            return 1;
        else if (integrityLevel == 0x2000)
            return 2;
        else if (integrityLevel == 0x3000)
            return 3;
        else if (integrityLevel == 0x4000)
            return 4;
        else
            return -1;
    }

    bool SetFileIntegrityLevel(int level, LPCWSTR FileName)
    {
        LPCWSTR INTEGRITY_SDDL_SACL_W;
        if (level == 0)
            INTEGRITY_SDDL_SACL_W = L"S:(ML;;NR;;;LW)";
        else if (level == 1)
            INTEGRITY_SDDL_SACL_W = L"S:(ML;;NR;;;ME)";
        else if (level == 2)
            INTEGRITY_SDDL_SACL_W = L"S:(ML;;NR;;;HI)";

        DWORD dwErr = ERROR_SUCCESS;
        PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = NULL;

        PACL pSacl = NULL;
        BOOL fSaclPresent = FALSE;
        BOOL fSaclDefaulted = FALSE;

        if (ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptorW(
            INTEGRITY_SDDL_SACL_W, SDDL_REVISION_1, &pSD, NULL))
        {
            if (GetSecurityDescriptorSacl(pSD, &fSaclPresent, &pSacl,
                &fSaclDefaulted))
            {
                dwErr = SetNamedSecurityInfoW((LPWSTR)FileName,
                    SE_FILE_OBJECT, LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
                    NULL, NULL, NULL, pSacl);

                if (dwErr == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            LocalFree(pSD);
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**IntegrityLevel.def** - зачем-то прицепил, но без него проект не работал

```
LIBRARY INTEGRITYLEVEL
```

Теперь о том, как собранной библиотекой пользоваться.

```
[DllImport("<директория>\\IntegrityLevel.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int GetFileIntegrityLevel(string FileName);

[DllImport("<директория>\\IntegrityLevel.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern bool SetFileIntegrityLevel(int level, string FileName);
```

Comment: Круто, чё. Маленькая нативная библиотека — правильный путь.

Comment: @VladD по-другому проблему решить всяко не удалось.

Comment: Но это хороший путь. Сложный нативный код, работающий с WinAPI, лучше держать в нативном виде. Заодно и вероятность ошибок меньше.

Answer (score 0):

Собрала dll, но при использовании падает ошибка 
Additional information: Не удается найти точку входа "GetFileIntegrityLevel" в DLL 
Попробовала просмотреть dll в PE Explorer, и там говорится, что ни одна функция не экспортируется.
Копировала ваши файлы, собирала dll в Visual studio (если это важно)

Comment: Это ответ или вопрос?

Comment: Возможно, не соблюдена **кодировка** или **разрядность** библиотеки и используемого приложения. Так же необходимо запускать приложение от **администратора**.

Comment: всё это соблюдено

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, да, разобралась, запустила.
Теперь новые проблемы:
1. В SetFileIntegrityLevel INTEGRITY_SDDL_SACL_W в самом начале не определена, и компилятор ругается. Что туда лучше скормить, чтобы не повлиять на работу?
2. По SetFileIntegrityLevel понятно, что 0 - Low, 1 - Medium, 2 - High.
Что соответствует Untrusted и System. В GetFileIntegrityLevel 4 варианта - какие?
3. На данный момент на все файлы мне возвращается 0 при получении и false при попытке изменить.

Comment: 1 - Он определен в этой функции строкой LPCWSTR INTEGRITY_SDDL_SACL_W;

2 - В данной программе нет возможности установить эти уровни целостности для файла. По моему, их нельзя выставить в принципе.

3 - Смотрите в коде, в GetFileIntegrityLevel  следующие варианты
<!-- language: lang-cpp -->
 if (integrityLevel == 0x0000) // Untrusted
 else if (integrityLevel == 0x1000) // Low
 else if (integrityLevel == 0x2000) // Medium
 else if (integrityLevel == 0x3000) // High
 else if (integrityLevel == 0x4000) // System
<!-- language: lang-cpp -->

Comment: а что тогда делает функция SetFileIntegrityLevel?

Comment: она устанавливает новый уровень целостности для файла.

Comment: >  2 - В данной программе нет возможности установить эти уровни целостности для файла. По моему, их нельзя выставить в принципе.

Comment: Простите, косяк отправки)
Идея в том, что сообщением выше Вы сказали, что менять уровень целостности нельзя. И при этом SetFileIntegrityLevel его меняет?

Comment: Ключевое слово **эти** - Untrusted и System, их нельзя установить для файла. Низкий, средний и высокий можно установить.